# String column doesn't exist in array column

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to check if value from a **string type column** (not a string itself) doesn't exist in another array type column.

I tries something like this:

```py
~col('string_column').isin(col('array_column'))
```

but since they are not the same type it fails

and also:

```py
~col('array_column').contains(col('string_column'))
```

but this fails due to datatype mismatch.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_contains` with the columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('contain', ~F.expr('array_contains(array_column, string_column)'))
```